# puppeteer being redirected when browser is not

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Attempting to test page https://publicindex.sccourts.org/anderson/publicindex/
When navigating with standard browser to the page, the navigation ends at the requested page (https://publicindex.sccourts.org/anderson/publicindex/) with the page displaying an "accept" button.

However, when testing with puppeteer in headless mode, the request is redirected to https://publicindex.sccourts.org.

I have a rough idea of what is occuring, but can not seem to prevent the redirection to https://publicindex.sccourts.org when the page is requested using puppeteer.
here is what I believe is occuring with the user controlled browser:

1. request for page is sent. (assuming first visit)
2. the response is pure JS,
3. The js code specifies to:

   copy the initial page request headers

   add a specific header, and re-request the same page (xhr)

   copies a url from one of the response headers and replaces the location

   (or)

   checks the page history,

   adds the url from the response to page to history,

   opens a new window,

   writes the xhr response to the new page

   closes the new window

   adds an event listener for a function in the returned xhr request

   fires the event

With puppeteer I have tried tracing the js, recording har, monitoring cookies, watching the request chain, intercepting page requests and adjusting headers,watching history....etc.   I'm stumped.
Here is the most basic version of the puppeteer script:

```html
function run () {
    let url = 'https://publicindex.sccourts.org/anderson/publicindex/';
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const PuppeteerHar = require('puppeteer-har');
    puppeteer.launch({headless: true}).then(async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1280});
        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
        const har = new PuppeteerHar(page);
        await har.start({path: 'results.har'});
        const response = await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await har.stop();
        let bodyHTML = await page.content();
        console.log(bodyHTML);
    });
};
run();
```

why can I not get puppeteer to simply replicate the process that is being executed by js when I am navigating to the page in chrome, and end navigation on the "accept" page?

here is a version with more verbose logging:

```html
function run () {
    let url = 'https://publicindex.sccourts.org/anderson/publicindex/';
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const PuppeteerHar = require('puppeteer-har');
    puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        await page.setViewport({width:1920,height:1280});
        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on('frameattached', frame =>{ console.log('frame attached ');});
        page.on('framedetached', frame =>{ console.log('frame detached ');});
        page.on('framenavigated', frame =>{ console.log('frame navigated '); });
        page.on('requestfailed', req =>{ console.log('request failed ');});
        page.on('requestfinished', req =>{ console.log('frame finished  '); console.log(req.url())});

        let count = 0;
        let headers = '';
            page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
                console.log('requesting ' + count + 'times');
                console.log('request for  ' + interceptedRequest.url());
                console.log(interceptedRequest);
                if (count>2) {
                    interceptedRequest.abort();
                    return;
                }
                if (interceptedRequest.url() == url) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1) {
                        const headers = interceptedRequest.headers();
                        headers['authority'] = 'publicindex.sccourts.org';
                        headers['sec-fetch-dest'] = 'empty';
                        headers['sec-fetch-mode'] = 'cors';
                        headers['sec-fetch-site'] = 'same-origin';
                        headers['upgrade-insecure-requests'] = '1';
                        interceptedRequest.continue({headers});
                        return;
                    } else {
                        interceptedRequest.continue();
                        return;
                    }

                }
                count++;
                interceptedRequest.continue();
                return;
            });
            const har = new PuppeteerHar(page);
            await har.start({ path: 'results.har' });
            await page.tracing.start({path: 'trace.json'});
            await Promise.all([page.coverage.startJSCoverage({reportAnonymousScripts  : true})]);
            const response = await page.goto(url);
             const session = await page.target().createCDPSession();
             await session.send('Page.enable');
            await session.send('Page.setWebLifecycleState', {state: 'active'});
            const jsCoverage = await Promise.all([page.coverage.stopJSCoverage()]);
            console.log(jsCoverage);
            const chain = response.request().redirectChain();
            console.log(chain + "\n\n");
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await har.stop();
        let bodyHTML = await page.content();
        console.log(bodyHTML);

    });
};

run();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the expected results and the current behavior? What do you mean by "the navigation ends with the page displaying an "accept" button"? And have you tried to run without headless mode to check what's going on visually?

Comment: I edited the post to be more clear. In regards to testing without headless mode to watch for visual changes, there are no visual changes that seem to occur when manually navigating to the url in chrome.  The whole process occurs immediately after the initial navigation request to the page.  So there is no time for any mouse movement detection or other user input detection. But I will try non-headless mode.

Comment: I managed to reproduce locally. Weird indeed lol

Comment: I found the problem, writing up

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full resolution but I know where the redirection is happening.

I tested your script locally with below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const PuppeteerHar = require('puppeteer-har');

function run () {
    let url = 'https://publicindex.sccourts.org/anderson/publicindex/';
    puppeteer.launch({headless: false, devtools: true }).then(async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on('request', request => {
            console.log('GOT NEW REQUEST', request.url());
            request.continue();
        });

        page.on('response', response => {
            console.log('GOT NEW RESPONSE', response.status(), response.headers());
        });
        await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1280});
        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
        const har = new PuppeteerHar(page);
        await har.start({path: 'results.har'});
        const response = await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await har.stop();
        let bodyHTML = await page.content();
    });
};
run();
```

I edited three parts:

- Removed headless mode and open the devtools automatically
- Intercept all network requests (that I audited)
- Hoisted `require` import because it hurts my eyes. I always see them call without nesting

Turns out the page `https://publicindex.sccourts.org/anderson/publicindex/` make a request to `https://publicindex.sccourts.org/`

However this request returns a 302 Redirect to `https://www.sccourts.org/caseSearch/` location, so the browser acts accordingly

[image]

I would try to investigate this weird request if it is legit or not and why it redirects on chrome puppeteer

This [post](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1453) might help, there could be something related on chromium being seen as insecure

I also tried to pass `args: ['--disable-web-security', '--allow-running-insecure-content']` to launch() object parameter, but without results

Please let us know how it goes! Har has been fun to discover!

Comment: Thanks for the input.   When testing manually, a request to https://publicindex.sccourts.org/ is not made.   It seems as though that request/redirection is occurring in headless/headful mode, but is not occuring when i manually navigate to the target url.  While attempting to intercept each request to check headers/cookies, i did notice I am unable to add set some specific headers sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin

Comment: Yeah there is something odd happening with chromium, I would reach out puppeteer. Try to open a new tab and enter manually the address, same thing happens all the time. This is browser level. I would try to set flags. Also you could try firefox, https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-firefox

Comment: I added a version with more verbose logging....  Again... thanks for having a look!