# CORS issue in Cypress test automation. "chromeWebSecuirty": false does not work in Chrome latest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automated-tests, cors, cypress

This problem is not something I am the only one facing. But this is something which will be a deciding factor ( make or break decision ) if we want to go with Cypress vs another test automation tool.

We have an application where the application once when it arrives at a specific page ( say Page C ) automatically redirects to Page D which is a totally different domain.

To give a better context, say Page A, Page B and Page C is from domain [www.newscorp.com](http://www.newscorp.com) and Page D, Page E and Page F is from [www.theage.com.au](http://www.theage.com.au)

After arriving at Page C ( the domain here is [www.newscorp.com](http://www.newscorp.com) ), the application automatically redirects to Page D (  [www.theage.come.au](http://www.theage.come.au)  )

What is the status of CORS issue in Cypress. All things look great in Cypress except redirection? Everywhere I read setting  "chromeWebSecuirty": false in Cypress JSON will resolve this. But not sure which version are they talking this?

I am currently using Chrome 85 with latest version of Cypress. Any help is deeply appreciated. [image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing the test code?

Comment: @MaximeHelen - Thanks for your comment. Have added the comments. Can you please help me here.

Comment: This is hard to tell what's going on with the code you share. I would like to debug locally like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203053/puppeteer-being-redirected-when-browser-is-not/63203527#63203527)

Comment: @MaximeHelen - Thank you very much for your comment. We expect the redirection to happen if everything goes well. Since everything is going well, we get the successPageUrl. All I am looking for is whether the page is loaded and and some logo validation to make sure the flow works. Not sure how Cypress handles redirection. Not sure whether it is a limitation in Cypress?

Comment: Have u tried   "chromeWebSecurity": false property in your cypress.json ?

Comment: @Karan - yes. I did that too. But not working. Thanks for your help.